# React (useState): Changing an Object Property from Child Element

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Hello guys I'm having hard time  on changing a single object property from another from child side.

```
import ComboData from './ComboData.js'
export default function BasicTabs() {

  const [country, setCountry] = useState({ selectedID: 0, data: [{ id: 1, text: "USA" }, { id: 2, text: "PORTUGAL" }] });

  return(
     <div>
        <ComboData type="text" name={"country"} label={"Country"} selectd={country.selectedID}
                valueData={country.data} idRef={"data.id"} valRef={"data.text"}
                setValOut={setCountry({...country, [country.selectedId]})}
                placeholder={"Select Your Country"}
              />
     </div>
  (
```

ON THE OTHER SIDE...

```
function ComboData({ name, label, placeholder, value, idRef, valRef, setValOut}) {
    return (
        <div>
            <label htmlFor={name}>{label}</label>
            <select onChange={(e) => setValOut(e.target.value)} name={name} value={selectd}>
                <option value="0" disabled>{placeholder}</option>
                {valueData ? (valueData.length > 0 ?
                    valueData.map(
                        (item, index) => <option key={item[idRef]} value={item[idRef]} id={item[idRef]}>{item[valRef]}</option>
                    ) : (
                        <option disabled>empty</option>
                    )
                ) : (
                    <option disabled>empty</option>
                )}
            </select>
        </div>
    )
}
export default ComboData;
```

I expeted that when a option is selected from my ComboData it has to update only the SelectedID of the useState..
LIKE THIS...

FROM:

`country{[{ selectedID: 0, data: [{ id: 1, text: "USA" }, { id: 21, text: "PORTUGAL" }]}`

TO:

`country{[{ selectedID: 1, data: [{ id: 1, text: "USA" }, { id: 2, text: "PORTUGAL" }]}`

OR

`country{[{ selectedID: 2, data: [{ id: 1, text: "USA" }, { id: 21, text: "PORTUGAL" }]}`

ISSUES:

1- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')

2- By DELETING the Line `valueData={country.data}` ===> Uncaught Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.
at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16187:1)

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues with your code. First, you need to pass the props with the exact same name to your component. For example, you defined:

```
function ComboData({ /*...*/ value, /*...*/ })
```

But passed:

```
<ComboData
  /*...*/
  valueData={country.data} 
  /*...*/
/>
```

Second, but related to the first, you used `valueData` inside `ComboData`, but the prop name is `value` as shown above.

Third, passing big object props like these can cause a lot of problems, because:

- Everytime a single part of it changes, it has to update the whole component, not only the child that depends on that specific part of the object prop. In other words, if `country.selectedId` changes, all `options` from map updates, because the state have changed.
- Consequence of the up above, memory usage would go nuts depending on how much this state changes. That's why you 're getting the second error you mentioned.
- I'm not certain if it applies here, but it may cause bugs due to shallow copies instead of deep copies.

Additionally, I think that first error occurs due to `useState` "set..." not being instantaneous. You can't use await in it, but it does need some time to change the state. I'd recommend a loading state to make sure it had enough time to update.

However, I'd recommend you to refactor it to something like this instead:

```
const [selectedCountryId, setSelectedCountryId] = useState(0)
const [countryOptions, setCountryOptions] = useState([{...}, {...}])
```

And pass those as separated props

An optimization could be done if `countryOptions` (equivalent to your `country.data`) never changes:

```
const countryOptions = [{...}, {...}]
```

Hope this helps. Good luck!